# Git for Windows can`t solve backslash '\' in path address

Tags: windows, git, backslash

I have installed Git 2.30, and selected all the default recommended options, but it doesn't seem to be able to access the **`.gitconfig`** file at my home directory, as the address has a backslash `\`.

The command returns a error message that ignores the `\` character, concatenating the following string.

[image: Git Bash screenshot]

As you can see, it concatenates the directories **`aidmin`** (admin user) with **`git`** folder, completely ignoring the backslash.

Said error appears on Git Bash, CMD and Powershell.
Should I reinstall with Unix formatting?
Also, unfortunately I can`t install other OS in this machine.

Comment: I see you made ti work, well done! What was your `%HOME%`/`$HOME` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, 2.3 is old, try and install the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.30.0(2))

Second, check what `$HOME` looks like.

It should be `/c/Users/admim`, or, in a CMD, it (`%HOME%`) should be set to `%USERPROFILE%`.
If not, in your bash session, try for testing to export HOME:

```
export HOME=/c/Users/admim
git config --global user.name "xxx"
```

Comment: Actually, it my version is 2.30, i typed it wrong, sorry. But the %HOME variable WAS wrong, being instead what was being returned on the screenshot, so that wasn't Git's fault. Howhever, i can't pinpoint why and how it changed to said value.

Thank you, you solved my problem.

Comment: I ran into a variant of this problem (backslash *inside* .gitignore) even on 2.33.1.windows.1 but git version 2.25.1 on Linux got me out of the jam.